# Stand alone off-line html5 web apps?

Tags: javascript, css, ipad, html

If I write an html5 web app for an iPad and plan on having it use local storage when the user is off-line.... is there a way I could wrap everything up in a zip-file and send it in a email then have then deploy it themself?

Can you get an off-line iPad web app going without being on-line and downloading it?

Something like this...
http://sixrevisions.com/web-development/html5-iphone-app/
and then send it as a package to someone else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not by default, no. iOS (for some reason) has no concept of "local storage" outside an App's own sandbox, that's why Mobile Safari can't download or upload files (besides photos).

The solution is to use a platform like PhoneGap which lets you use the HTML5 platform to create native-like applications (that also work on Android and WinPho too). It's easy to get started with it, so I suggest you give that a go.

Comment: So I will have to put the app online and let the user go to the page then it will be added to local storage?

Comment: No. "local storage" does not exist (note that I'm not talking about HTML5 local storage). Just use PhoneGap: http://phonegap.com/